# Using charmcraft to build an application with subordinate charm "docker charm"

Tags: juju

I am working on packing an application using charmcarft tool. The application, named [Concourse CI](https://concourse-ci.org/) is running in a docker-composed way.
After reading quite a few documents online, I guess I can use the subordinate [charm-docker](https://ubuntu.com/kubernetes/docs/1.21/charm-docker) to complete my job.
I have followed the [hello-operator](https://juju.is/docs/sdk/hello-world) tutorial to come out with a template for my principal charm. But I still have hard time to bring things together.
There are 2 main questions:

1. To charcraft build my docker-compose application, what need to be verified in meta.yaml, config.yaml, and charm.py? I need an example but I can hardly got one.
2. How to connect principal charm with subordinate charm when deploying the application using juju?

Comment: Also clone this question to
https://discourse.charmhub.io/t/using-charmcraft-to-build-an-application-with-subordinate-charm-docker-charm/4739

Answer (score 0):

There is already someone working out the first version of it here:

https://discourse.charmhub.io/t/using-charmcraft-to-build-an-application-with-subordinate-charm-docker-charm/4739